# Magento 2 - How to upload image and some post data to REST API (POST)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api, magento2.4

I'm working with a Magento 2 project that need to upload image and post data using a POST endpoint

How can I send image with post array data.If post request sample available then share.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: do you want to upload product images using rest api?

Comment: No i want to upload images in my custom module